# Python efficient way to filter dict

Tags: python, json, performance, dictionary, filtering

I have a *JSON* file that's pretty easy (but really big) and I need to filter it a bit. (I havent done any python for a while now...)

It looks like this:

```
{
    'entry_1': {
        'field_1' : 'value',
        'field_2' : 123,
        'field_3' : '',
        'field_4' : 456
    },
    'entry_2': {
        'field_1' : 'value',
        'field_2' : 321,
        'field_3' : 'value',
        'field_4' : 654
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to filter it to remove the useless fields. My test file being small what I've done works well but I'll need to do it on a pretty big file and I know my code is pretty ugly.

So far I've done this:

```
dict_in = json.load(INFILE)
dict_out = defaultdict(dict) #4harambe

allowed_fields = {'field_1', 'field_3'} 
'''should I use a set or a tuple here ? or maybe something else
All data inside will be unique (set) but 
those data wont change (tuple)
'''

for entry in dict_in:
    for field in dict_in[entry]:
        if field in allowed_fields and not dict_in[entry][field]:
            # allowed field plus non empty string
            dict_out[entry][field] = dict_in[entry][field]
```

I'd like to know how I can make it a bit sexier and more efficient (the double loop + if statement is pretty bad along with the way I access the data). I've read about itertools but I don't know how to use it yet and if it's a good idea.

Comment: Leave it as a `set()` O(1) vs. tuple O(n). Also, from the answers below, yours is the most readable and exactly the possibly same performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it using [`dictionary comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
allowed_fields = {'field_1', 'field_3'}
dict_out = {
    entry_key: {
        field: field_value
        for field, field_value in entry_value.items()
        if field in allowed_fields and field_value
    }
    for entry_key, entry_value in dict_in.items()
}
```

which gives all `field_1` and `field_3` keys with non-empty values:

```
{'entry_1': {'field_1': 'value'},
 'entry_2': {'field_1': 'value', 'field_3': 'value'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
dict_out = {k: {f: v[f] for f in allowed_fields if v.get(f)} 
            for k, v in dict_in.items()}
```

**Note:**

*If you're still using python 2.7, use `.iteritems()` not `.items()`*

Comment: Good answer. One caveat: for Python 2.7 it'd be better to use `.iteritems()` instead, since `.items()` makes a separate `list` of all the items—which is pretty inefficient for large objects. In Python 3.x this is unncessary.

Comment: @DanLenski I've added that as a note for compatriots still suffering under the oppressive yoke of 2.7

Comment: @donkopotamus… can't argue with you there. Time to get back to the toiling-in-the-ancient-proprietary-database-module-mines.

Comment: @donkopotamus dindn't get that part ! I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @DanLenski there needs to be more humor on SO, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate over the inner `dicts` just grab the values directly:

```
def grabber(d, fields, default=None):
    return dict((f, d.get(f, default)) for f in fields) 

dict_out = {k:grabber(v, allowed_fields) for k,v in dict_in.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `dict_in` as an input and `fields` that you need:

```
fields = ['field_1', 'field_4']
dict_out = dict([(k, {_k: _v for _k, _v in v.items() if _k in fields}) for k, v in dict_in.items()])
```

`dict_out` will look like this:

```
{'entry_1': {'field_1': 'value', 'field_4': 456},
 'entry_2': {'field_1': 'value', 'field_4': 654}}
```